# Rewriting JS to TS leads to weird errors when it comes to React.Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have perfectly working and simple React JS context like below. Really, it can't be simpler.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const SelectedCurrenciesContext = React.createContext();

const SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currencyBase, setCurrencyBase] = React.useState(null);
    const [currencyCrypto, setCurrencyCrypto] = React.useState(null);

    return (
        <SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider
            value={{
                currencyBase: currencyBase,
                currencyCrypto: currencyCrypto,
                setCurrencyBase: data => setCurrencyBase(data),
                setCurrencyCrypto: data => setCurrencyCrypto(data),
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider;
```

Now try to have the same in Typescript and problems begin.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { baseCurrencyType } from '../types';

type ContextType = {
    currencyBase?: baseCurrencyType | null;
    currencyCrypto?: string | null;
    setCurrencyBase?: (currencyBase: baseCurrencyType) => void;
    updateTodo?: (currencyCrypto: string) => void;
};

interface ContextTypeInterface {
    currencyBase?: baseCurrencyType | null;
    currencyCrypto?: string | null;
    setCurrencyBase?: (currencyBase: baseCurrencyType) => void;
    updateTodo?: (currencyCrypto: string) => void;
}

const InitialState = {
    currencyBase: null,
    currencyCrypto: null,
};
export const SelectedCurrenciesContext = React.createContext<ContextType | null>(null);

const SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider:React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [currencyBase, setCurrencyBase] = React.useState<baseCurrencyType | null>(null);
    const [currencyCrypto, setCurrencyCrypto] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

    return (
        <SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider
            value={{
                currencyBase: InitialState.currencyBase,
                currencyCrypto: InitialState.currencyCrypto,
                setCurrencyBase: data => setCurrencyBase(data),
                setCurrencyCrypto: data => setCurrencyCrypto(data),
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider;
```

It throws basically two errors (technically more but guess the rest is generated be these two. The first error is at

```
    <SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider
```

line and it says

```
Cannot find namespace 'SelectedCurrenciesContext'
```

The second one is at

```
const SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
```

and it says (what is probably consequence of first one)

```
children is declared but its value is never read
```

I have tried with or without defaultState( no success, seems it is a must) with defaultState being null, and also with passing state items not like above but only as

```
const [currencyBase, setCurrencyBase] = React.useState<baseCurrencyType | null>(null);
```

No matter how I do it, the errors does not vanish, however. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

interface SelectedCurrenciesContextProps {
    currencyBase?: baseCurrencyType;
    currencyCrypto?: string;
    setCurrencyBase: (currencyBase: baseCurrencyType) => void;
    setCurrencyCrypto: (currencyCrypto: string) => void;
}
const SelectedCurrenciesContext =  createContext<SelectedCurrenciesContextProps>({} as SelectedCurrenciesContextProps);

function SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const [currencyBase, setCurrencyBase] = useState<baseCurrencyType | undefined>(undefined);
    const [currencyCrypto, setCurrencyCrypto] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

// Same names will be recognized, no need to do currencyBase:currencyBase

    return (
        <SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider
            value={{
                currencyBase,
                currencyCrypto,
                setCurrencyBase,
                setCurrencyCrypto,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider>
    );
}

export {
 SelectedCurrenciesContextProps,
 SelectedCurrenciesContext,
 SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider
};
```

Comment: Thank you - but really, it does not help - Same error at   <SelectedCurrenciesContext.Provider
Cannot find namespace 'SelectedCurrenciesContext'.
I start to suspect config problem -but have no idea which

Comment: @Kiszuriwalilibori, can you double check your file extension? Should be `.tsx` instead of .`ts`.

Comment: You are right, it was a case

Answer (score 0):

Add explicit type to your provider:

```
const SelectedCurrenciesContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {}
```

Comment: It does change but it does not solve . Error from {children} goes away but another appears at the same line :Type '({ children }: { children?: ReactNode; }) => {}' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2322)

Comment: get rid of `:JSX.Element`

Comment: Done,  no change in errors

Comment: Can you update the questions with latest changes?

Comment: Yes of course, done

Comment: hmu on linkedin, this might need some digging 
https://www.linkedin.com/in/karan-kumar-456098127/